# Call another view using delegates

Tags: swiftui

I have my own Button control, very similar to swift 5.

My protocol:

```
public protocol RoundedButtonDelegate {
    func click(button:RoundedButton)
}
```

My control:

```
public struct RoundedButton : View {
    
    public var text:String = ""
    public var backgroundColor:String = ""
    public var borderColor:String = ""
    public var textColor:String = ""
    public var width:CGFloat = 0
    public var height:CGFloat = 0
    public var fontSize:CGFloat = 0
    public var delegate:RoundedButtonDelegate?
    public var controlId:String = ""
    
    init(id:String = "", text:String, width:CGFloat, height:CGFloat, fontSize:CGFloat = 19, theme: Theme = Theme.light, delegate:RoundedButtonDelegate?) {
        
        if theme == Theme.light {
            self.backgroundColor = LightColorSchema.mainColor.rawValue
            self.borderColor = LightColorSchema.mainText.rawValue
            self.textColor = LightColorSchema.mainText.rawValue
        }
        
        if theme == Theme.dark {
            self.backgroundColor = DarkColorSchema.mainColor.rawValue
            self.borderColor = DarkColorSchema.mainText.rawValue
            self.textColor = DarkColorSchema.mainText.rawValue
        }
        
        self.controlId = id
        self.text = text
        self.width = width
        self.height = height
        self.fontSize = fontSize
        self.delegate = delegate
    }
    
    public var body: some View {
        ZStack {
            Button(action: {
                print(">Redirect to next page")
                self.delegate?.click(button: self)
                
            }) {
                HStack(alignment: .center, spacing: 5.0) {
                    Text(self.text)
                        .font(.custom("Montserrat-SemiBold", size: self.fontSize))
                        .foregroundColor(Color.init(hex: self.textColor))
                        .padding(.all, 10.0)
                }
                //.frame(width: UIScreen.main.bounds.width - 80, height: 48, alignment: .center)
            }
            .padding(.all, 10)
            .frame(width: self.width, height: self.height, alignment: .center)
            .overlay(
                RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: self.height / 2)
                    .stroke(Color.init(hex: self.borderColor), lineWidth: 1)
            ).background(RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 40).fill(Color.init(hex: self.backgroundColor)))
        }
        .frame(width: self.width, height: self.height, alignment: .center)
        
        
    }
    
}
```

This is not an special control, is just to define some UI componentes. Well, in my view I have the implementation like:

```
func click(button: RoundedButton) {
        print("Execute protocol")
        switch button.controlId {
        case "btnSesion":
            return
        case "btnTarjeta":
            return self.redirectSeleccionarTarjeta() //Here is accessing!
        default:
            print("No defined action")
        }
    }
```

And this is the method that I need to solve:

```
func redirectSeleccionarTarjeta()  {
        print(">Redirect")
        self.showLinkTarget = true
        
        
        //self.navigate(to: InicioSolicitarTarjetaView(), when: $showLinkTarget)
        
            self.fullScreenCover(isPresented: $showLinkTarget, content: {
                InicioSolicitarTarjetaView()
                            })
//        NavigationLink(destination: InicioSolicitarTarjetaView(), isActive: self.$showLinkTarget ) {
//           Spacer().fixedSize()
//        }
    }
```

How can I redirect to another view from a delegate action? Is that possible?
I tried in several ways, but no luck

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rather than using `self.fullScreenCover` in your button callback, you need to actually use it in your view hierarchy.  Then, just change the `showLinkTarget` value in your callback.  The next time the view is rendered, the `fullScreenCover` should be presented.

Simplified example:

```
@State var showWindow = false

Button(action: {
    showWindow.toggle()
}) {
    Text("Open window")
}.fullScreenCover(isPresented: $showWindow, content: {
    Text("Content")
})
```

Note that this is within the view hierarchy -- not the button's action callback.

See more detailed info about using `fullScreenCover`: https://www.hackingwithswift.com/quick-start/swiftui/how-to-present-a-full-screen-modal-view-using-fullscreencover

Comment: You're right. I didn't notice `fullScreenCover` can be used in a big number of components, it helped me a lot to understand, thanks!